# Set QGIS 2.18 as default on Win with both 2.18 and 3.0

Tags: qgis, windows, qgis-3

Is there a way to have both QGIS 3.0 and 2.18 installed on one computer but have 2.18 as the default Package when opening workspaces. At the moment 3.0 opens all my workspaces which is rather annoying as most of the Plugins and providers I'm using are not available yet in 3.0. It was more of a test download to familiarise myself with the newest version until it is brought up to LTR standard. OS is Windows 10

Comment: One method could be to right-click a `.qgs` file and go to _Properties > General_ and change the `Opens with` setting to the batch file used by QGIS 2.18. For me, it's in `C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/bin/qgis-ltr.bat`. I tested this before on Win7, not sure about Win10.

Comment: For those of waiting for plugins in 3, the real drawback between switching back and forth is the loss of saved maps in Composer Manager, when reverting from 3 to 2.18.  Until the plugins I need are available, I am deleting 3 from my production computer and installing it on a test machine.

Comment: @Pooneil I save projects edited in QGIS 3 under a different name to avoid mashups. A separate folder might work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For standalone installations, go to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\bin`, for OSGEO4W64, to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-ltr\bin` (not tested here, I only have QGIS 3.0 and qgis-dev in OSGEO4W64).

Doubleclick on qgis.reg, and the version will be used as default for opening .qgs files.